# Conditional WHERE clause using IF statement SSRS 2005

Tags: plsql, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am having some trouble with SSRS that I think should be pretty basic. I've seen some answers regarding IIF statements and others, but not quite addressing this.

I am new to SSRS so I'm not sure what code/syntax you are able to use in the Data section using PLSQL.

All I want to do is have a if statement that is based on whether or not a parameter is null. I've tried all sorts of syntax but it keeps throwing errors. Any Suggestions?

Something like:

```
IF (:start_date IS NULL) THEN

SELECT wo.wonum, wo.worktype, wo.description wo_description, wo.targcompdate, wo.assetnum,         
s.siteid, s.description s_description, 
round((wo.targcompdate - sysdate), 0) DaysTillDue
FROM workorder wo
INNER JOIN site s on wo.siteid = s.siteid
WHERE 
(wo.targcompdate - sysdate) >= :Low_Day
and (wo.targcompdate - sysdate) <= :High_Day
and wo.siteid = :site_param
and wo.worktype = :worktype_param; 

ELSE

SELECT wo.wonum, wo.worktype, wo.description wo_description, wo.targcompdate,   wo.assetnum,         
s.siteid, s.description s_description, 
round((wo.targcompdate - sysdate), 0) DaysTillDue
FROM workorder wo
INNER JOIN site s on wo.siteid = s.siteid
WHERE 
(wo.targcompdate - sysdate) >= :Low_Day
and (wo.targcompdate - sysdate) <= :High_Day
and wo.siteid = :site_param
and wo.worktype = :worktype_param
and targcompdate between :start_date and :end_date; 

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use a dynamic SQL expression (although these are generally deprecated due to considerations such as SQL injection), but given that the only difference between the two queries is the additional final condition, I suggest the following query instead:

```
SELECT wo.wonum, wo.worktype, wo.description wo_description, wo.targcompdate, 
       wo.assetnum, s.siteid, s.description s_description, 
       round((wo.targcompdate - sysdate), 0) DaysTillDue
FROM workorder wo
INNER JOIN site s on wo.siteid = s.siteid
WHERE (wo.targcompdate - sysdate) >= :Low_Day
  and (wo.targcompdate - sysdate) <= :High_Day
  and wo.siteid = :site_param
  and wo.worktype = :worktype_param
  and (:start_date is NULL or targcompdate between :start_date and :end_date)
```

Comment: How exactly does that last and statement work? Will it basically bypass if that :start_date param is NULL?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqopr.htm#i1004871 - within the brackets, if *either* expression is true, then the *whole* of the bracket are treated as true; so if `:start_date` is null, then it doesn't matter what `targcompdate` is, whereas if `:start_date` has a value, then it has to check whether `targcompdate` is in the specified range.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've haven't used the OR much in this context, or with parameters so was a little confused at first. Makes sense though. Thanks again.